# unable to run video in WPF

Tags: wpf, video

I try to implement a video in WPF. The video is visible in Visual Studio (so I think the path is correct) but isn't visible (I also hear nothing) while I run the program. I have 1 MediaElement to implement the video and 3 Buttons (Play, Pause, Mute) below. The Build-Property of the video is "Resource".

XAML-Code:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="340" Height="300" Margin="281,63,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <MediaElement Name="myMedia" Source="testvideo.wmv" LoadedBehavior="Manual" Width="320" Height="240" />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0">
        <Button Content="Play" Margin="0, 0, 10, 0" Padding="5" Click="mediaPlay"/>
        <Button Content="Pause" Margin="0, 0, 10, 0" Padding="5" Click="mediaPause"/>
        <Button x:Name="muteButt" Content="Mute" Padding="5" Click="mediaMute"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myMedia.Volume = 100;
    myMedia.Play();
    myMedia.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5); // first frame 5 seconds
}

void mediaPlay(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myMedia.Play();
}

void mediaPause(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myMedia.Pause();
}

void mediaMute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myMedia.Volume == 100)
    {
        myMedia.Volume = 0;
        muteButt.Content = "Listen";
    }
    else
    {
        myMedia.Volume = 100;
        muteButt.Content = "Mute";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to give path on using uri path. or is you video in different folder then you have to assign path like Source="Videos/testvideo.wmv"

Comment: Code and video are in the same folder.

Comment: Do you have an exception or an error in the out of your software ?
Cause your code seems correct

Comment: Make sure that video is marked as "Resource", by default All images and Videos are marked as "Content" which will not be copied when we build the solutions.

Comment: I have no errors and the video is marked as Resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem:
I had to set the property "Source" of the MediaElement in the code behind again. I don't know why, but now it works!